# UnCaught Type Error Cannot Read Properties Of Undefined Reading Name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, jsx

when i log in to the website i simply redirect it to the /account page where i have shown  details of the user
then on account page i have simply dispatched a redux store action that gets the logged in user details
and then using useSelector hook i get that userState's State and pulled out user and other properties
when i try to render user details in jsx it gives me undefined.....
this is my /account component
`

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getUserDetails } from "../../actions/userLoginAction";
import Loader from "../Loader/Loader";
import "./Account.css";
const Account = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { user, loading } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getUserDetails());
    }, [dispatch]);
    return (
        <>
            {loading ? (
                <Loader />
            ) : (
                <div className="userDetails">
                    <div className="personalInformation">
                        <div className="name  text-center">
                            <h1>Full Name</h1>
                            <p>{user.name}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="email text-center">
                            <h1>Email</h1>
                            <p>{user.email}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="joinDate text-center">
                            <h1>Joined On</h1> <p> 10-22-2022</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="editprofilebox">
                        <button>Edit Profile</button>
                        <button>My Orders</button>
                        <button>Change Password</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default Account;
```

`

Ive tried passing user props from the app.jsx on first render it shows details but when i refresh the account page it again runs into undefined error`

```
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./components/layouts/header/Header";
import Footer from "./components/layouts/footer/Footer";
import Home from "./components/Home/Home";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import ProductDetails from "./components/ProductDetails/ProductDetails";
import NotFound from "./components/NotFound";
import SearchedProduct from "./components/SearchedProducts/SearchedProduct.jsx";
import AllProducts from "./components/AllProducts/AllProducts";
import LoginRegister from "./components/LoginRegister/LoginRegister";
import Account from "./components/Account/Account";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { getUserDetails } from "./actions/userLoginAction";
import { store } from "./Store";
import UserActions from "./components/UserActions/UserActions.jsx";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Loader from "./components/Loader/Loader";
function App() {
    const { user, isAuthenticated, loading } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
    useEffect(() => {
        store.dispatch(getUserDetails());
    }, []);
    return (
        <Router>
            <Header />
            {isAuthenticated && <UserActions user={user} />}
            <ToastContainer />
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/products/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
                <Route path="/products" element={<AllProducts />} />
                <Route path="/:keyword" element={<SearchedProduct />} />
                <Route path="/loginregister" element={<LoginRegister />} />
                <Route
                    path="/account"
                    element={<Account user={user} loading={loading} />}
                />
                <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
            </Routes>
            <Footer />
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

`

Comment: what is the initial value of `user` ?

Comment: ive set inital state to an empty object

Comment: so is the error ... `state.user` -> gives `undefined` and `undefined.name` throws the error you got ...  you can add a default value as `const { user={}, isAuthenticated, loading } = useSelector((state) => state.user);`

Comment: HAHAHA!!! Literally i was expecting like it would be a stupid and short sol. But my mind fucks! i didnt thought about that .....Thanks Alot Brother!!! Fixed It In A Milli Second